# Does React native or Flutter supports on demand resource?

Tags: react-native, flutter, mobile

We are planning to use hybrid technologies( React Native or Flutter) for developing a mobile application, we need to include on Demand Resource support at a later stage. Anyone knows can we achieve on Demand Resource support in React Native or Flutter

Comment: what is a demand resource support?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

We want functionalities similar to this ie Download the necessary module only when its required ie when user tries to acess that functionality